# DbContext SqlQuery returns unexpected result

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, code-first, dbcontext

I've got two entity classes `User` and `Connection`, and `User` has a collection of `Connection`.

```
class User
{
    public string username {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Connection> Connections {get; set;}
}

class Connection
{
    public string ConnectionId {get; set;}
    public string RoomName {get; set;}
}
```

I've got this SQL Query which retrieves a list of connections for a user

```
// this code can be moved to the database as a stored procedure or view
var sql = @"SELECT   Users.UserName, Users.UserPix,
                                Connections.ConnectionId, Connections.RoomName, Connections.DateCreated
           FROM            Users CROSS JOIN  Connections
           WHERE        (Users.UserName = @p0) AND (Connections.RoomName = @p1)";

return _context.Users.SqlQuery(sql, username, roomName).FirstOrDefault();
```

It returns a user object with an empty connection list, rather than populating the connections with data returned from the database.
I've tried replacing cross-join with inner-join but still the same result

I don't know how else to modify the sql query so that the actual data is returned. How can I do this or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think you can return child objects with SqlQuery unless you use lazy loading.

Comment: i think the sql query can be modified in a way that will enable a perfect transformation maybe something like a subquery or something.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the SqlQuery method instead of just querying the users entities directly with linq?

Comment: @MattyM I'm trying to get a list of connections for a user to a particular room

Comment: As DavidG and Matty say, Raw SQL does not allow to include the related entities, so you need to use linq to get the user entity and use include to populate the connections collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you aren't doing anything special here (there aren't even any projections) you can just return the entities directly from the context, including the navigation properties you want with them:

e.g. given these entities:

```
class User
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
}

class Connection
{
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
}
```

A one-to-many relationship should exist in your database between User -> Connection

In order to get all connections for a particular user, or all connections for all users, or any combination of queries you can think of with filters/aggregates etc on users/connections whilst preserving the relationship you can just use `.Include()` from `QueryableExtensions` in `System.Data.Entity`

Signature is as so if you are interested:

`public static IQueryable<T> Include<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path) where T : class`

Which is a good thing about EF, you can eager load the child entities on demand without having to mess with the entity design or add new entity classes which don't contain the navigation properties

So basically it boils down to this:

```
using(YourDbContext context = new YourDbContext())
{
    var query = context.Users.Include(user => user.Connections);

    // Do stuff with query
}
```

Don't forget about deferred execution - if you don't know what deferred execution is, and how a query is built up in EF it's worth looking it up - the general rule of thumb is; the less queries that hit the database and the less crunching you do in C# (for database style operations like aggregates) the quicker your app is going to perform - so make sure you don't enumerate the results until you've fully built the query or you are going to be doing all the number crunching on the .NET side using LINQ to objects, not in SQL where it should be!

So calling `.ToList()` or enumerating the above query will get you the results

EF will translate anything you have done to the correct SQL dialect using the provider you have chosen (likely `System.Data.SqlClient`). You don't need to write any SQL...

Some other examples of queries you might do:

```
// Get me users called Fred including their connection details
context.Users.Include(x => x.Connections).Where(u => u.Username == "Fred")

 // Get me users that are currently connected to "Game Room"
context.Users.Include(x => x.Connections).Where(u => u.Connections.Any(c => c.RoomName == "Game Room")
```

None of this requires you to write any SQL - put a SQL trace on when running these queries to see what EF does, and usually it will write queries better than you ever could :) (only sometimes it doesn't and it's usually when you are doing something silly)

**Edit**

Ok I see you are trying to filter both the user and the connections that come back over the wire, in that case you either need to explicitly load the navigation property as a separate query or use projection to do the filtering

e.g.

**Explicit Loading**

```
var user = context.Users.First(x => x.UserName == username);

context.Entry(user).Collection(x => x.Connections).Query().Where(x => x.RoomName == roomName).Load();
```

That does result in two queries

**Projection**

```
var usersConnections = context.Users
.Where(u => u.UserName == userName)
.Select(u => new
{
    User = u,
    Connections = u.Connections.Where(c => c.RoomName == roomName)
});
```

This results in an anonymous type which contains a `User` property and a `Connections` property. You can always project into a known type too if you need to send this over some sort of domain boundary

This will be a single query against the datasource

Comment: I'm working with the explicit loading approach as it returns the user and connection, the projection style returns a list of user and connections which you have to project/transform to your expected type.

Comment: You can just new up the type during the projection if you want instead of creating an anonymous type, unless you are happy with the small performance penalty of multiple queries (and it will likely be very small)

Comment: I tested both queries on LinqPad, the one with projection returned an `IEnumerable<User>` and `IEnumerable<Connection>`. The `User` collection has it's connection list populated with the correct value and the list of `Connection` has the same connections. If I project to a named typed it will have to be a a type with properties for `IEnumerable<User>` and `IEnumerable<Connection>`, and then pick out the first element `type.Users.FirstOrDefault()` which return a user and it's associated connection. I guess explicit loading will have very little perfomance hit or i might use projection?

Answer (score 0):

To do this I first retrieve/check if the user exist, then I retrieve their connections and add it to the list of connection for that user

```
public User GetUserAndConnections(string username, string roomname)
{
    var user = _context.Users.Find(username);
    if (user != null)
    {
        var connections =
            _context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == username)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Connections.Where(p => p.RoomName == roomName))
                .ToList();
        user.AddExistingConnections(connections);
    }

    return user;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use entity framework and navigation properties for this? Why are you cross joining? Cross join returns a row from the right table for every row in the left table. You want a left join - but really you don't want a join you want entity framework to do that for you

Comment: You are basically missing the whole point of an ORM when writing simple non provider specific SQL against the data source. You could get the same result using `context.Users.Include(x => x.Connections)`

Comment: @Charleh can you show an example. you can even edit the answer

Comment: @Charleh I've re-written it to use linq. My intent is to retrive the user with it's list of connection to a room. In my scenario a user can connect to a room from different devices and a new connection will be created and mapped to that user for the room. I want to retrive the user and it's connection details to that room and to do this I use the linq query above. Can I have a single query retrieve the user and the connections to a room.

Comment: Yes, the query I posted gives you exactly that - `context.Users.Include(x => x.Connections)` - it retrieves all users and their connections, to filter for a particular user use `context.Users.Include(x => x.Connections).Where(u => u.UserName == username)`. If you want any users in a particular room its `context.Users.Include(x => x.Connections).Where(u => u.Connections.Any(c => c.RoomName == roomName))` - you can get anything you want out of it without projecting. You only need to project if you want to flatten the data, modify the data or aggregate the data (and a few more uses)

Comment: If you omit the `Include` it will still give you the correct results based on joining the tables, but it will not populate the `Connections` navigation property on the `User` entity (it still JOINs and WHEREs but it only SELECTs for the `User` table)

Comment: I've tried this `Users.Include(x => x.Connections).Where(u => u.Connections.Any(c => c.RoomName == roomName))` which you suggested above before asking my question, but i get undesired result. It returns users and it's connection but the returned connections included connections to other rooms. I've looked through the sql generated and it does a left outer join and applies the `where`  clause but the result seems like it never did filter the connections

Comment: Ah yes sorry that *will* include all connections - it only checks to see if any of the users connections are in the room you are looking for, it doesn't filter the connections from the results that come back, hang on give me a second to update

Comment: Yeah I've added it as an edit to the existing answer